# How to create noise on an audio file in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, noise

I wanted to create a noise on an audio file and have the ability to do this in any part of the audio file that I wanted to do .. Thank you for helping ....

I wrote this but it does not solve my problem:

```
load handel.mat;
hfile= 'handel.wav';
wavwrite(y, Fs, hfile);
nsamples=Fs;

[y, Fs , nbits, readinfo]= wavread(hfile,nsamples);

sound(y(round(2.85/4*end):end),Fs);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why this should creat noise `y(round(2.85/4*end):end)`?

Answer (score 0):

### Adding Noise to a Specific Portion of a Signal

In this example, two variables named `Start_Time` and `End_Time` are used to indicate where the noise begins and ends in seconds. To convert these times to find the corresponding sample indices we can divide the `Start_Time` and `End_Time` by the `Sampling_Period` which is `1/Sampling/Frequency`. After finding these indices, `Start_Sample` and `End_Sample` we can use matrix-indexing to extract the specific portion of the signal between the range and add our noise model. In this case, I simply used a random vector that ranges from -1 to 1 by implementing the `rand()` function. The code below also outlines an alternative option commented out that uses the `awgn()` function to apply Additive White Gaussian Noise (AWGN). Depending on your noise model this may differ. Hopefully, the code outlining how to extract/target a portion of the audio helps.

[image: Audio Plot Comparison]

### Adding Random White Noise:

```
load handel.mat
File_Name = 'handel.wav';

audiowrite(File_Name,y,Fs);
[Original_Signal,Sampling_Frequency] = audioread('handel.wav');
Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;

%Selecting region to apply noise (1s to 3s)%
Start_Time = 1; %1 second%
End_Time = 3; %3 seconds%

Start_Sample = Start_Time/Sampling_Period;
End_Sample = End_Time/Sampling_Period;

%Random noise vector%
Noise_Strength = 0.1;
Noise_Vector = Noise_Strength.*(2*rand(1,End_Sample-Start_Sample+1)-1).';
Noisy_Signal = Original_Signal;

%Random Noise%
Noisy_Signal(Start_Sample:End_Sample) = Noisy_Signal(Start_Sample:End_Sample) + Noise_Vector;

%Additive White Gaussian Noise (AWGN)%
% Signal_To_Noise_Ratio = 20;
% Noisy_Signal(Start_Sample:End_Sample) = awgn(Noisy_Signal(Start_Sample:End_Sample),Signal_To_Noise_Ratio);

sound(Noisy_Signal,Sampling_Frequency);
```

---

### Extension: Visually by Plotting

```
Audio_Properties = audioinfo('handel.wav');
Total_Samples = Audio_Properties.TotalSamples;
t = (0: Sampling_Period: Sampling_Period*(Total_Samples-1));

clf;
subplot(2,1,1); plot(t,Original_Signal);
title("Original Audio Signal");
xlabel("Time (s)"); ylabel("Amplitude");
ylim([1.2*min(Original_Signal) 1.2*max(Original_Signal)]);

subplot(2,1,2); plot(t,Noisy_Signal);
line([Start_Time Start_Time],[1.2*min(Noisy_Signal) 1.2*max(Noisy_Signal)],'color','r');
line([End_Time End_Time],[1.2*min(Noisy_Signal) 1.2*max(Noisy_Signal)],'color','r');
text((End_Time + Start_Time)/2,(max(Noisy_Signal)-min(Noisy_Signal))/2,"Noisy Region",'color','r','HorizontalAlignment','center');
title("Noise Added to Portion of Audio Signal");
xlabel("Time (s)"); ylabel("Amplitude");
ylim([1.2*min(Noisy_Signal) 1.2*max(Noisy_Signal)]);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: You might want to note that this code only adds *white* noise to the audio signal.

Comment: I’d second that. It is not clear from the question if the requirement is `1 / f` noise, brownian noise or harmonic noise. The use of `round` in the question suggests some kind of noise modelling. In the Spirit of SO, I think it is best the author clarify the question first

Comment: The author might very well need white noise, but at that point it would be best practice to point towards an existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5Dnoise and close the question

Comment: Very good points that I overlooked. Thank you, my bad for not considering the various noise models he/she could be trying to implement.